# What happens for an useEffect with no second argument or one equal to null or undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I just wanted to know how `useEffect` will behave if we pass the second argument as `null` or `undefined` in place of the dependencies array. Will it render on every cycle? Or just once? Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create an `useEffect` with no second argument or one equal to `undefined` or `null`, yes the callback will get executed on every render. And if you have explicitly typed `undefined` or `null` as the second argument, and you have Eslint in your editor you would get this warning:

```
React Hook useEffect was passed a dependency list that is not an array literal. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

That's with no harm to your application in a case like below where you don't mutate a `state` inside the callback, it will just log "Hello Word" every time there is a render.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState]= useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hello Word");
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {()=>setState(!state)}>Toggle State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It will cause an infinite loop of renders in cases like below where you mutate a `state` inside the callback. That's because a state change triggers a render, and the callback gets executed on every render.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState]= useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
   setState(!state);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {()=>setState(!state)}>Toggle State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And to cover all the use cases, there is the one with an empty dependencies array as the second argument, where the callback gets executed only on the first render:

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState]= useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
   setState(!state);
  },[]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {()=>setState(!state)}>Toggle State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And finally, the one that calls the callback on the first render and every time some `state` in the dependencies array changes:

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState]= useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
   console.log("Hello Word");
   // setState(!state); if you mutate state here, it will cause an infinite loop of renders
  },[state]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {()=>setState(!state)}>Toggle State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will rerender every circle if deps is not defined or is null.

In React source, when the second argument is not defined, deps will be `null`,  [updateEffectImpl](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/167853026cb193f81c0474d3bf9ef9e03dde203e/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.old.js#L1679), will always execute pushEffect, and render every circle :

```js
function updateEffectImpl(fiberFlags, hookFlags, create, deps): void {
  const nextDeps = deps === undefined ? null : deps;

  if (currentHook !== null) {
    // .eg
  }

  // always execute
  hook.memoizedState = pushEffect(
    HookHasEffect | hookFlags,
    create,
    destroy,
    nextDeps,
  );
}
```